# Trouble with Gem version ahead of what Rubygems expects

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I seem to have an issue with the version of a gem that I am using.
I have no internet access, I downloaded the gem straight from the Rubyforge and then SCPed it to the target machine and I used `gem install --force --local` to install it. Ruby/Rubygems comes from a snapshot of the EPEL repo taken about a month ago. It is hosted on on a machine in the network and YUM is configured across the network to point to the correct location.

I am trying to use the Net::SSH family of gems (Net:SSH, Net::SSH::Shell, Net::SSH::Multi, Net::SSH::Gateway, Net::SCP). When I run my `file.rb` I get this:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: net-ssh(2.6.6 not ~> 2.1.0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate' 
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from ./cluster_config.rb:12
```

I have seen a lot of issues around the internet about the actual version being less that than the expected version, but I have only found on example where the actual version was newer than the expected, but it was "resolved" with a response from the OP saying "My buddy got it, thanks."

This is also the first time I have seen the `~>` operator in this use. Usually I have seen the `>=` operator here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`~>` is used inside Gemfiles to allow a gem to be used whose patch version is greater or equal to the specified version, provided that the major and minor versions are identical. For example:

`~> 2.1.0` would allow version `2.1.9`, but not `2.2.0` or `2.0.0`.

`~> 2.1.3` would also allow `2.1.9` but not `2.1.0` or `2.2.0`.

Also, you could probably download the exact version you need directly from RubyGems. In your case, the link would be http://rubygems.org/downloads/net-ssh-2.1.0.gem .

Comment: Hm, it seems silly that I would have to downgrade the version of the gem that I am using just to make rubygems accept it. Is it asking for an older version because the newer one is not vetted enough?

Comment: There may be changes in version `2.2` that the application isn't compatible with or hasn't been tested with. As the application has been tested to work with version `2.1`, the developers chose to use that version. Also, multiple versions of a gem can exist on a system, provided they aren't loaded simultaneously.

Comment: I installed the older Gem and it complained that it wasn't 2.5.0 or greater. A little digging and Net::SSH::Gateway/Multi and Net::SCP require >= 2.5.0 and Net::SSH:Shell requires ~> 2.1.0. Looks like I can't use Net::SSH:Shell with the other three so I will need to work around using it.  Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: You could try to find versions of Net::SCP, et al that work with Net::SSH 2.1.0. It might require some manual digging around, but even if the gem isn't listed on RubyGems.org you may still be able to manually download a version by using a URL similar to the one I used in my answer.